# How to get Start Date, Close Date, Email, Contact Number, Interst Rate and Term of loan fields value from Opportunity section in SOAP API php?

Tags: opportunity

Please help me to suggest "Start Date, Close Date, Email, Contact Number, Interst Rate and Term of loan" fields name.
I am using SOAP API in php and have a salesforce trail account .

This is running code is :-

```
$query = "SELECT Id, Name, Type, Amount, OwnerId, CloseDate FROM Opportunity ";
$Opportunity = $mySforceConnection->query($query);
```

Am try to get this fields value but not successful. So please help me and suggest best tutorial point.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You will need to do following things.

1) download and set  the php toolkit in Apache(just copy the source files)  https://developer.salesforce.com/page/PHP_Toolkit
2) call login SOAP api, pass credentials, get session id
3) call query api and pass the query that you want to perform

Here is sample code for your reference.

```
<?php
// SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR - folder that contains the PHP Toolkit and your WSDL
// $USERNAME - variable that contains your Salesforce.com username (must be in the form of an email)
// $PASSWORD - variable that contains your Salesforce.com password

define("SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR", "../../soapclient");
require_once (SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR.'/SforcePartnerClient.php');
require_once (SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR.'/SforceHeaderOptions.php');

require_once ('../userAuth.php');

try {
  $mySforceConnection = new SforcePartnerClient();
  $mySoapClient = $mySforceConnection->createConnection(SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR.'/partner.wsdl.xml');
  $mylogin = $mySforceConnection->login($USERNAME, $PASSWORD);

  $query = 'SELECT Id,Name,BillingStreet,BillingCity,BillingState,Phone,Fax from Account Limit 1';
  $response = $mySforceConnection->query($query);
  $queryResult = new QueryResult($response);

  for ($queryResult->rewind(); $queryResult->pointer < $queryResult->size; $queryResult->next()) {
    print_r($queryResult->current());
  }

} catch (Exception $e) {
  print_r($mySforceConnection->getLastRequest());
  echo $e->faultstring;
}
?>
```

For more details refer https://developer.salesforce.com/page/PHP_Toolkit_13.0_Getting_Started

Comment: Thanks Atul, But we are all ready use the php toolkit and also get the ID, name and Close date from Opportunity. But am fetching problem to get more fields "Start Date, Close Date, Email, Contact Number, Interst Rate and Term of loan" fields value from Opportunity .

Comment: Did you added those fields in query? are facing any issue? any error?

Comment: Please can you tell me these fields name. Am more effort to searching, but......

Comment: Custom field on every org can be different. You can figure out field name by login into salesforce -> got to setup -> quick find opportunity -> fields.